# Update references to pictures on website after moving to new URL

Tags: database, urls, content, references

I moved my wordpress website to a new URL on the same server and managed to update most DB entries with the Velvet `Blues Update URLs` plugin. But the paths to my pictures, which are being used by the theme were not updated. Now the website can't load them anymore. The pictures' URLs still point to the old place. Is there tool, which can fix that, so I don't have to search for all entries in the DB by myself?

Comment: Where are these referenced? Did you hard code paths in your template files?

Answer (score 0):

Besides doing a custom query in your MYSQL database, I've found this little script to be helpful in my development process, and I've incorporated into my regular workflow to keep my local, development and production servers synchronized:

https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Just be sure to read the documentation, especially about overwriting GUID values and also make sure to delete the script after you've made the changes!

Comment: the problem about this tool is, that it seens to replace the whole value assigned to an attribute if it contains the searched phrase. is there a way to replace only the substring of a value?

Comment: Without understanding your specific case, typically when I transfer my db from local, let's say the URL is `something.dev`, and the production is `something.com`, I always append the protocol `http:` before the url `http:something.dev` (or whatever your URL is, includes `www`, etc). That seems to correctly target the URLs in media files. I'd suggest backing up your DB and experimenting.

Comment: I just updated all my URLs, but now the whole theme reseted itself and looks like freshly installed. What might be the reason?

Comment: Hmm, is this a live site do you have a URL to look at?

Comment: Even if I change one single value by hand in the DB, like the background, the theme uses the standardpicture for it. The updated URL is definitely correct, since I can access it with the browser. 

EDIT: what do you mean by live site? if it's online? The server is up and running.

Comment: When you updated the URL with `searchreplacedb2.php` did you edit values in the existing db that you previously edited with the `Blues Update Plugin` or with a fresh upload of your db with the old URL?

Comment: After running the `Blues Update Plugin`, which restored my pages correctly (but without pictures), I ran the `search and replace plugin`. After that I restored the DB to that point, before I ran the second plugin and changed one value manually to see what would happen.

Comment: Try to restore the DB to the original, before you made any changes, then run the `search & replace` plugin on the unmodified DB.

Comment: same result, all pictures disappeared and the theme looks like freshly installed. only the subpages still exist

Comment: Is the site public? Can you share the URL with me? Actually nix that idea, unless you delete the search & replace db script first.